# How to insert Time in a range of excel sheet which should not update automatically using com object in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to insert time in a range which should not get updated automatically. For example if there is any value in cell no k5 then the current time should automatically be inserted in cell no N5. Similarly if there is any value in k6 then the current time should be automatically be inserted in N6, so on.. One more thing I Wish to bring in your kind notice that there is also a formula in entire column K, so If I type any value in any cell left to column K it shows the calculated result in its corresponding cell (in column K). Moreover the time should not be updated automatically. I tried to use this formula

=IF(K5<0,"",IF(K5=0,"",NOW()))

This formula is working but it is auto updating the time with the system's clock. I want it should not update the time. You can see the snapshot also:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: In Excel on the Mac, command semi-colon will insert the current time as a static value, so I'd image there's a similar keystroke in Windows Excel, and if not you could add one with Excel's menu and keystroke customization.

Comment: You asked this identical question the day before and received an answer several weeks ago.  Gary's Student spent considerable time developing and customizing a solution for you, and you didn't even upvote it.  JJohnston2 obviously spent considerable time developing another answer for you here, and you have not even upvoted this answer either.  From your comments, it appears you lack the knowledge to implement the type of solution required.  Training you in VBA is outside the scope of a question or answer.  People will stop answering your questions if you abuse people's time in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a com object in AutoHotkey but I wouldn't recommend doing it that way.

If you place a `Worksheet_Change()` macro into your spreadsheet Excel will evaluate it each time you manually enter something (i.e., when you update a cell or change it).  The macro will receive the Range object of the cell(s) modified, so from the range object you can get the row and column.  If the column is a column you care about (in your case, column `K`), then you use the same row and a different column (in your case, column `N`) to insert the time.  The `Worksheet_Change()` macro will get called for all spreadsheet updates any time a cell changes, so it is important to distinguish which columns you care about, since the routine will also execute for any updates on columns you do not care about as well.

The code example below should be easy for you to adapt.  It is designed with a few variations that you can remove and adapt to your situation.

1. It is designed to insert the date, not the time... that is easy to change
2. It is designed to trigger on multiple columns, not just one column
3. To allow flexibility in redesigning the spreadsheet or moving columns around, it is not hard-coded to a particular column, i.e., `K` or `N`.

Description of Item 3 in detail:

- The code does not rely on hard-coded column address values
- Instead it relies on the first row `MyRange = Range("1:1")` being a header row (which usually looks nice also)
- Once the header row is defined (i.e., hard-coded as row `1`), it then finds the column headers which are important to trigger an update
- After it finds those column headers, it checks to see if the cell that changed was in one of those columns
- If the cell was in one of those columns, then the Date is inserted

This setup allows you to use a labeled header row in the first row and move columns around later at will (insert or delete columns wherever), and still have the auto-insertion work correctly even if the cells you care about are no longer at the same `K` or `N` column locations any longer.  If you don't care about that of course you can just leave your spreadsheet without headers, strip out the `WorksheetFunction.Match` code and use hard-coded column addresses.

To use this code, open the VBA editor--typically there will be a tree on the left showing VBAProject (Filename) with a sub-folder for Microsoft Excel Objects and then sub-items for each of the three sheets (by default on a new workbook) as well as ThisWorkbook.  Double-click on the Sheet that you want it to work on and then insert the `Worksheet_Change()` function below so you can use and edit it for that sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   'Do nothing if more than one cell is changed or content deleted
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    'Debug.Print Time
    MyRange = Range("1:1")
    TotalColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Total", MyRange, 0) 'exact match, row 1
    ProjectColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Project", MyRange, 0) 'exact match, row 1
    DescriptionColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Description", MyRange, 0) 'exact match, row 1

    If Target.Column = TotalColumn Then   ' If Total gets updated, then update the Total change date

        DateColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Date Last Total Change", MyRange, 0) 'exact match, row 1
       'MsgBox DateColumn

        ' ------------------------------------------------
        ' EnableEvents not required, but keeps this routine from being called again
        ' ------------------------------------------------
        Application.EnableEvents = False     

        'Update field with Date of last update
        ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, DateColumn).Value = Date

        Application.EnableEvents = True     ' re-enable events
        ' ------------------------------------------------

    End If

    If (Target.Column = TotalColumn) Or (Target.Column = ProjectColumn) Or (Target.Column = DescriptionColumn) Then

        DateColumn1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Date", MyRange, 0) 'exact match, row 1

        ' Update the open date if it's empty, otherwise leave it alone
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, DateColumn1).Value = "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, DateColumn1).Value = Date
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks dear @JJohnston2 for your kind reply. Could you please tell me how to set codes according to my requirement, as i am newbie in vba codes. please help me.